# How to use a java function in libgdx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

*Hi, I wanna use a java (in AndroidLauncher) function in libgdx. Please help me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you're trying to call method of `AndroidLauncher` class which is in `android module`.

You can use interfacing for your requirement.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: is there an easier way to call a method from android module

Comment: I think this is the quite easier method, and for me this is only solution in my mind.

Comment: Can ı get data from method after call method. So I wanna call a method from libgdx and get result data of the method

Comment: yes through method return type